# Initialise Flatpickr on click

Tags: jquery, flatpickr

I currently call flatpickr as follows:

```
$("#FieldID").flatpickr({enableTime: true,minDate: "today",time_24hr: true,altInput: true});
```

However I need to send datetime data to the field before it initialises. I've tried the following:

```
var updatecalendar = new Flatpickr(document.getElementById("FieldID"));
updatecalendar.set({enableTime: true,minDate: "today",time_24hr: true,altInput: true});
```

Which sets the date, however it doesn't use any of the settings that I have set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#date").flatpickr({
   enableTime: true,
   minDate: "today",
   time_24hr: true,
   altInput: true,
   defaultDate: "2018-04-24 16:57"
});
```

For more details see https://jsfiddle.net/egdqeajt/